# Check for duplicates in a database and report back whether a new record was created or not

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a repeated pattern in my code that I feel is an antipattern. I have an `sqlalchemy` engine set up as this:

```
engine = create_engine(Config.CONN_STRING)
autoengine = engine.execution_options(isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")
```

When I want to make a new entry, using raw SQL I have, e.g.:

```
class ProductCategory(Base):
    
    __tablename__ = 'product_categories'
    
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    
    @staticmethod
    def create_new(
        name: str
    ):
        with autoengine.connect() as conn:
            
            q = text(
                """
                SELECT 
                    name
                FROM
                    product_categories
                WHERE
                    name = :name
                """)
            
            data = list(conn.execute(q, {'name': name}))
            if data:
                return False, f"Product category: {name} already exists"
            
            q = text(
                """
                INSERT INTO product_categories (
                    name
                )
                VALUES (
                    :name
                )
                """)
            
            conn.execute(q, {'name': name})
            
            return True, f"Product category: {name} successfully created"
```

To me, it should be possible to have a single query to do this *and* report back whether it was successful or not (note the `return` statements giving me a tuple to give back to the frontend in both cases). I've had a go with CTEs and gone down the path of something like `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING EXCLUDED.name` but the primary key is not `name`, it's an auto-generated `id` and I got lost. I can do the reverse no problem because I get an `id` from the frontend:

```
@staticmethod
def delete(id_: int):
​
    with autoengine.connect() as conn:
        
        q = text(
            """
            UPDATE
                unit_measures
            SET
                is_deprecated = true
            WHERE
                id = :id
            RETURNING
                name
            """)
        
        deleted = list(conn.execute(q, {'id': id_}))
        if not deleted:
            return False, "Unit measure ID not found"
        
        return True, f"Unit measure successfully deleted: {deleted[0][0]}"
```

Is there a way to consolidate the two queries into one? This is Postgres but I'm happy for any dialect if the approach can be translated.

---

To clarify: I am well aware of race conditions and I know how they are likely with the current setup. If creating a `UNIQUE` constraint or an index is *necessary* to consolidate my query, that's an acceptable answer. However, it would be great if there is a solution that uses the existing DB setup (no index on `name`).

Comment: Any chance you can implement it as a UNIQUE constraint in your   SQL db?

Comment: I could make `name` unique, yes, if that helps

Comment: Then you can use INSERT in a try/catch block

Comment: That can't be the industry standard, surely? I know the "easier to ask for forgiveness" principle, but do we really use it in this case?

Comment: Yes it's a rather common way of trying to insert a row and catching UNIQE constraint exception . No SELECT, INSERT only.

Comment: That's a most unsatisfying answer in that case so let's say I can't add the `UNIQUE` constraint on `name`

Comment: A legitimate answer, btw, is "this can't be done" but it is so ridiculously simple in its principle and yet I can't find any way to do it

Comment: @roganjosh Serg is correct. Consider if two processes are trying to insert the same thing at the same time. If they try to insert and check, once inserts and one doesn't. Good. If you check then insert, both check and both insert. Bad. This is called a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and is a very common problem in concurrency. You want to **do and be rejected** not check then do. This is *very important* when using any shared resource like a database or file system.

Comment: @Schwern see my comments under the existing answer. I'm well aware of this, which is why I want it to be consolidated but I can't figure it out

Comment: @roganjosh You can't avoid adding the unique indexes. You'll want them regardless, and any other necessary constraints to ensure data integrity. Then you can scrap all that special insert code and create the record normally and look for the exception. Don't return if it succeeded or not, not at the model level, let the model throw an exception. Deal with it at a higher level.

Comment: well, poop :P Thanks for the input; that's the second opinion I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you need to put a unique index on your `name` column

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_product_categories_name ON product_categories (name)
```

so you can do something like this

```py
class ProductCategory(Base):
    __tablename__ = "product_category"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100), unique=True)

    @staticmethod
    def get_or_create(name: str, session: Session) -> "ProductCategory":
        with session.bind.begin() as conn:
            result = conn.execute(
                text(
                    "INSERT INTO product_category (name) "
                    "VALUES (:name) ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING"
                ),
                dict(name=name),
            )
            print(
                f">>> INFO: {'returning existing category' if result.rowcount == 0 else 'category created'}"
            )
        return session.scalars(
            select(ProductCategory).where(ProductCategory.name == name)
        ).one()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"ProductCategory(id={self.id!r}, name={self.name!r})"
```

which you could use like so

```py
with Session(engine) as sess:
    pc = ProductCategory.get_or_create("shoes", sess)
    # >>> INFO: category created
    insp = inspect(pc)
    print(f"{pc}, persistent={insp.persistent}")
    # ProductCategory(id=1, name='shoes'), persistent=True
    another_pc = ProductCategory.get_or_create("shoes", sess)
    # >>> INFO: returning existing category
    print(another_pc)
    # ProductCategory(id=1, name='shoes')
    print(pc == another_pc)
    # True
```

Comment: I guess I can't avoid additional indexes in this case...

Comment: I want to leave this open for a bit. I know why you added the index, but it's not in my question and I wanted that circumstance answered

Comment: It's still going to emit two separate queries? That's the same logic just bundled up in the ORM?

Comment: I wouldn't be so arsed about this but it's in a web framework where I expect lots (thousands) of entries from a customer to get it off the ground as a system on day 1, so race conditions are definitely in the mix. If the index is the only way to go, then fine, it just means going back across all my table definitions. I hoped there would be an atomic approach without needing to add an extra index

Comment: Careful! You have a race condition. A classic check then write problem. If two processes try to create the same category at the same time they may both find that it doesn't exist and both try to create it. Your first implementation is correct, just try it and get rejected.

Comment: Even without the ORM ,`with engine.connect() as conn` starts a transaction

Comment: (Answer updated to remove race condition.)